# Значение слова "природный"

Tags: значение-слов

Подскажите, в каком значении было употреблено слово "природный" в следующем предложении:
"Природная предрасположенность человека к тем или иным видам
деятельности проявляется в социальных обстоятельствах".

Comment: @М_Г Было бы лучше разницу между вопросами со словами "природа" и "природный" объяснить в ответе. Ведь основное непонимание заключалось именно в этом.

Comment: @grizzly, Думаю, Антон  уже понял, что  "природа" и "природный" — разные слова. А для других читателей важно, чтобы вопрос был сформулирован корректно.

Answer (score 2):

"Природная предрасположенность" здесь синонимична "предрасположенности **от рождения**", речь идёт об индивидуальных биологических особенностях человека, которые проявляются, в частности, в избирательной способности к обучению разным видам деятельности. Кто-то *прирождённый* лингвист, а кто-то руководитель (напр. считается, что склонности к управлению имеются у 6% людей). Приблизительно такой же смысл ("от рождения, по рождению") имеет известная цитата, приписываемая Суворову в разговоре с Павлом I: "... а *природный* русак".